# Unable to create a bundle for Autodesk Design Automation Revit 2020

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-designautomation

When I try to create a bundle for Design Automation(DA) Revit 2020, I get the following message:

```
"data": {
    "Engine": [
        "Engine 'Autodesk.Revit+2020' is deprecated since 2023-03-29 (Parameter 'Engine')"
    ]
},
```

I also found information that the depreciation date is March 29, 2023, and the removal date is March 28, 2025: 
[Engine versions](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/engine-lifecycle/#engine-versions)

Based on this information, we have two years before it is removed.

This probably means that Autodesk continues to support old packages (created before 2023) and we can't create new ones after that date.

I would really appreciate it if anyone has any information on whether we can create a package for 2020 now.

I also try to create a bundle for DA Revit 2021 and everything works fine.
The problem occurs only when creating a bundle for the 2020 version.

Answer (score 0):

No, the creation of new activity and appbundles referencing Revit 2020 is now disallowed because Revit 2020 is deprecated since 3/29/2023, which means there is no technical support for this version anymore.
And WorkItem referencing the existing activity(and appbundles) on Revit 2020 still work till the removal date of Revie 2020, 3/282025.

Comment: Also, today I found my old application created before this date (3/29/2023), and when I tried to update the bundle, I got the same problem. 
To summarize, I can't do any bundle manipulation (create, update) with the Revit 2020 Engine. 
Am I right?

Comment: yes, it is correct

Answer (score 0):

There is a new Engine Lifecycle Policy -
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/engine-lifecycle/

I discovered today that is not possible to create a work item with a deprecated engine, really annoying actually.

Comment: Also, today I found my old application created before this date (3/29/2023), and when I tried to update the bundle, I got the same problem. 
To summarize, I can't do any bundle manipulation (create, update) with the Revit 2020 Engine. 
Am I right?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can update the bundle if you select a valid engine, in my case I only have one bundle for all the versions, as I know the work item overwrites the engine in the bundle.

But in the case of the work item, I'm not able to create/update with an old/deprecative version.